# How to get current date in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How to get current date in codeigniter in YY-mm-dd format. I wants to get current date in YY-mm-dd frmat and put this value into input text box

Comment: date("Y-m-d"). why you need codeigniter?

Comment: Hi suresh, i am new to on php.. i have no idea about to develop a php websites

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [PHP date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
date('Y-m-d');
```

Up to my knowledge, there is no separate date function in codeigniter.

**EDIT :**

But if you want date in this format `13-04-05 [ yy-mm-dd ]`, Try this

```
date('y-m-d');
```

For more date formats, check this link [**PHP Date Formats**](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ss/php_functions_3.htm)

Comment: all the answers posted here are giving you exactly the thing you want. What else do you need

Answer (score 6):

Try to use this is a generic format of DateTime

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

use php `date` function

```
echo date("Y-m-d");
```

will give you the result

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
$date = new \Datetime('now');
var_dump($date);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want the full date:

```
echo date('Y-m-d');
```

depends your date structure.

```
echo date('d-m-Y');
```

if you want year only, then  `echo date('Y');` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Use php date() function, like this
echo Date('Y/m/d');
it give you the desired result!