# How can I fetch data on codeigniter using current date?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my first question around here so be nice :)

I am trying to display data using Codeigniter and MySQL based on the current date.

Down below, there's my function from the Model.

When I use this format it works:

```php
public function get_tables(){
    $this->db->where('date','2020-04-07');
    $this->db->order_by('time', 'ASC');  
    $query=$this->db->get('tables');
    return $query->result();
}
```

But when I try to use the `CURDATE()` function, it shows me an error on this line.

```php
public function get_tables(){
    $this->db->where(date_format('date',"YYYY-MM-DD"),'CURDATE()', TRUE);
    $this->db->order_by('time', 'ASC');  
    $query=$this->db->get('tables');
    return $query->result();
}
```

I'll be glad to hear why isn't it working, any suggestions to improve it will be welcomed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current date in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830364/how-to-get-current-date-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

Your `date_format` call is wrong. The first parameter must be an actual date. Not the string "date". I think you're mixing PHP and MySQL.

By using `date_format` as second parameter you create a string of the current date with PHP and give it to MySQL.

```php
public function get_tables(){
    $this->db->where('date', date_format(new DateTime(), 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
    $this->db->order_by('time', 'ASC');  
    $query=$this->db->get('tables');

    return $query->result();
}
```

<strike>`CURDATE()` is a MySQL function and I don't think it's possible to give raw MySQL to `where()`.</strike>

edit: Dum answered this question. It's possible to use `CURDATE()` with Codeigniter:

```php
public function get_tables(){
   $this->db->where('date', `CURDATE()`, false);
   $this->db->order_by('time', 'ASC');  
   $query=$this->db->get('tables');

   return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Codeigniter documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

> $this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names.

So, You should use

```
$this->db->where(date_format(new DateTime(),"YYYY-MM-DD"),'CURDATE()', FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

use date() funtion

```
public function get_tables(){
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $this->db->where(date_format,$date);
    $this->db->order_by('time', 'ASC');  
    $query=$this->db->get('tables');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone, I combined all of your answers with this answer:

[how curdate function could return date in mm/dd/yyyy format php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991851/how-curdate-function-could-return-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-format-php)

and it worked!!

Posting the last version of my Model function for displaying data from DB based on the current date:

```
public function get_tables()
{

 $this->db->where('date =','DATE(CURDATE())',FALSE);
 $this->db->order_by('time', 'ASC');  
 $query=$this->db->get('tables');
 return $query->result_array();

}
```